# Flutter - Problem mocking supabase with mocktail

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, testing, supabase

I'm trying to mock a query to a table in Supabase with mocktail, and it doesn't work. My problem is mocking the await on the PostgrestTransformBuilder, it doesn't work at all:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

class MockPostgrestTransformBuilder extends Mock
    implements PostgrestTransformBuilder<PostgrestList> {}

void main() {
  final mockPostgrestTransformBuilder = MockPostgrestTransformBuilder();
  final myList = <Map<String, dynamic>>[];

  test('Mocking PostgrestTransformBuilder', () async {
    // defining the mock
    when(() async => mockPostgrestTransformBuilder)
        .thenAnswer((_) async => myList);

    // calling the mock
    final result = await mockPostgrestTransformBuilder;

    // expecting the result
    expect(result, myList);
  });
}
```

Can anybody help me?

I have tried a lot of things, and it doesn't work

Edit: I add here the "real code" I try to test. In this code, that is working perfectly calling Supabase objects, I have been able to mock:

- The SupabaseClient.from
- The SupabaseQueryBuilder.select
- The PostgrestFilterBuilder.order

But the final mock never works.

```
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

class MyService {   const MyService({required this.supabaseClient});   final SupabaseClient supabaseClient;

  /// read the data
  Future<void> readData() async {
    final a = supabaseClient.from('table_name');
    // a is SupabaseQueryBuilder
    final b = a.select();
    // b is PostgrestFilterBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>
    final c = b.order('column name', ascending: true);
    // c is PostgrestTransformBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>
    final d = await c;
    // d is List<Map<String, dynamic>>
    /* ... */
  }
  /* ... */
}
```

Thanks.

---

Edit v2

I try to put a complete example of the code I'm trying to test. The error I get is `type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<dynamic>'`, and I supose it's because I am not mocking the `final d = await c;`. But I don't know how to mock it...

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';

class MockSupabaseClient extends Mock implements SupabaseClient {}

class MockSupabaseQueryBuilder extends Mock implements SupabaseQueryBuilder {}

class MockPostgrestFilterBuilder<R> extends Mock
    implements PostgrestFilterBuilder<R> {}

class MockPostgrestTransformBuilder<R> extends Mock
    implements PostgrestTransformBuilder<R> {}

class MyService {
  const MyService({required this.supabaseClient});
  final SupabaseClient supabaseClient;

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> readData() async {
    final a = supabaseClient.from('table_name');
    // a is SupabaseQueryBuilder
    final b = a.select();
    // b is PostgrestFilterBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>
    final c = b.order('column name', ascending: true);
    // c is PostgrestTransformBuilder<List<Map<String, dynamic>>>
    final d = await c;
    // d is List<Map<String, dynamic>>
    return d;
  }
}

void main() {
  late MockSupabaseClient mockSupabaseClient;
  late MockSupabaseQueryBuilder mockSupabaseQueryBuilder;
  late MockPostgrestFilterBuilder<PostgrestList> mockPostgrestFilterBuilder;
  late MockPostgrestTransformBuilder<PostgrestList>
      mockPostgrestTransformBuilder;
  late MyService myService;
  late Map<String, dynamic> myList;

  setUpAll(() {
    mockSupabaseClient = MockSupabaseClient();
    mockSupabaseQueryBuilder = MockSupabaseQueryBuilder();
    mockPostgrestFilterBuilder = MockPostgrestFilterBuilder();
    mockPostgrestTransformBuilder = MockPostgrestTransformBuilder();
    myService = MyService(supabaseClient: mockSupabaseClient);
  });

  test('Mock test', () async {
    when(() => mockSupabaseClient.from(any()))
        .thenAnswer((_) => mockSupabaseQueryBuilder);
    when(() => mockSupabaseQueryBuilder.select())
        .thenAnswer((_) => mockPostgrestFilterBuilder);
    when(() => mockPostgrestFilterBuilder.order(any(), ascending: true))
        .thenAnswer((_) => mockPostgrestTransformBuilder);

    final result = await myService.readData();

    expect(result, <Map<String, dynamic>>[]);
  });
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code does not make sense. `final result = mockPostgrestTransformBuilder;` is `await`ing a `MockPostgrestTransformBuilder` object, not a `Future`.  Furthermore, `when(() async => mockPostgrestTransformBuilder)` will not create a stub on the `MockPostgrestTransformBuilder` object since it's not calling any methods on it.

Comment: Sorry, my initial code was too simple. I edited the question trying to explain better my problem, can you understand now my problem?

Comment: Your edited question doesn't correct any of the problems I mentioned, and the new code you've posted does not involve any mocks, so it doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: Apologies again, now I've provided a more complete code snippet with what I managed to mock and the error I'm facing. Unfortunately, I don't know how to answer your questions, so I hope that with the complete example you can better understand my issue and assist me.

Comment: Okay, I understand now. `MockPostgrestTransformBuilder<T>` implements `Future<T>`.  That's ... unusual.  I haven't been able to successfully mock `MockPostgrestTransformBuilder<T>`, but I'd suggest not mocking that and using a real `PostgrestTransformBuilder<T>` object instead if possible.

Comment: Thank you for the response. My problem now is that I don't know how to use a PostgrestTransformBuilder instead of a mock. Do you know of any examples where this is done? Thanks.